# "Realizing" and "building" something

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

If I have software SW, and I want to enhance its performance by adding a capability, say X, to it, what do I call this process?

Is it correct to say:

> Realizing X in SW?

Or:

> Building X in SW?

I feel that building and realization are not two suitable words for this reason.

Comment: If the capability is a performance enhancement, it might be better to re-craft the sentence to describe that effect with a more intuitive verb: "Speeding up SW with X" but it is hard to say what would work best without knowing more about X.

Comment: Could the phrase [*improving*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/improve) **SW** *with* **X** work?

Comment: @mattacular X is a property that makes SW to behave autonomously

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what "X" could be? If, for instance, X were "threading" than neither of your examples would work very well. In that case, "utilizing" may be a good option.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say either "implementing X" or "adding feature X."

Comment: These are not jargony, not sales-talkish, and not 50 cent word phrases when a dime'll do just as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think adding/added will suite better in the situation.

> For ex: Facebook has added video chat functionality with the help of ..
>
> Visual studio has now added features for enhanced security ..